# How I only get the first TDs of each TR, with Simple Html Dom?

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, find, simple-html-dom

I need to get only the first columns of all rows from a table using Simple Html Dom. How I do this?

```
foreach($html->find('table.horarios-filmes-single tr') as $tr) {

    foreach ($tr->find('td', 1) as $element) {
       echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
    }
}
```

This returns the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you with your problem,

```
$e = []; 
foreach($html->find('table.horarios-filmes-single tr') as $tr) {
    $e[] = $tr->find('td', 0); 
}
```

> 0 index will give you first instance of `td` in every `tr`

If still face any problem, you should `print_r($html->find('table.horarios-filmes-single tr'));` and check if you are getting any data.